# Cannot open Shapefile with any Python libraries, but it will open in QGIS/ArcGIS

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal

I have a shapefile that I cannot open in any open source Python libraries, including GDAL, Pyshp, Fiona, and Geopandas.  The error message: **Invalid length for entity 9164** is a GDAL error message and can be found in the source code: https://fossies.org/linux/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/shape/shpopen.c at lines 871 and 2121.  Both sections indicate that the error occurs during the reading/handling of offsets in the .shx file.  Here is the comment to the first section that the error message occurs at: **Read the .shx file to get the offsets to each record in the .shp file**

The really frustrating aspect of this issue is that the file can be viewed and edited in QGIS/ArcGIS with no issues.

If I open the shapefile in QGIS and then save it with a different name, I can open the *new* shapefile with all python libraries.  Upon further investigation, if I use the *new* .shx file with the original set of shp files, the file *also* opens in Python.  So somehow this is a corrupted .shx file.  Any info would be helpful as I have my processes automated.

Comment: Corruption in shapefiles is fairly common (and fairly annoying) usually (for me) it stems from a bad download. Have a read of https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000007161 there's a utility to download that fixes some errors.

Comment: The odd thing here is that I thought QGIS used gdal/ogr to read shapefiles. Is it using a different version, which traps the shx corruption and falls back to the slow method of scanning the .shp? Can you edit your Q and add the version info of QGIS, and the version of GDAL that QGIS is using - you can get this from the Help -> About menu somewhere. Versions of GDAL that your python scripts use might also help, and if you can let us have your shapefile (or one that fails similarly). I might try corrupting a .shx manually and see what happens...

Comment: While it is possible to read a `.shp` file without `.shx` under most conditions, it is difficult for most clients to distinguish the difference between a "hole" in the file (where record length and offset disagree), and true corruption of the offsets file. It seems as if the code library could be less pedantic, but it's hard to blame it for trying to prevent a segmentation violation.